# Null check operator used on a null value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm complete beginner into flutter plzz help me out!

[Here's the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46DnR.png)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column (
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: share the error message that you are getting on your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Please return class in main method. don't return MaterialApp.Please return MyApp which is your class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column (
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and also return in test/widget_test.dart file.

```
await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
```